# Geolocating tweets with ruby and twitter gem

Tags: ruby, twitter, geolocation

I'm trying to fetch geolocated tweets with Ruby, but for some reason it doesn't work and gives me some weird data.

This tweet should be geolocated (correct me if I'm wrong):
https://twitter.com/ngw/status/653875745899548672

The client is created exactly as in documentation, and in fact it "kinda" works...

```
tweet = client.status(653875745899548672)
=> #<Twitter::Tweet id=653875745899548672>
tweet.text
=> "Geolocating tweets must be the least used Twitter feature."
tweet.user.screen_name
=> "ngw"
```

Unfortunately I can't make the geo part work...

```
tweet.geo?
=> false
tweet.geo
=>
```

Am I doing something wrong? Apparently yes, my tweet is clearly geolocalized, but the gem is telling me it isn't.
Thanks in advance.